# I need to analyse buying pattern of consumer buying data

Tags: data-request, products

I need to analyse the consumer buying data to predict what the customer will buy when he back to the shopping mall again.

My problem is data sets - where can I get the appropriate data sets for this ?

Comment: This is like business sensitive data. Who will give you?

Comment: Is there any open data available for researches

Answer (score 6):

A quick search found [this page](http://fimi.ua.ac.be/data/), which cites a link to data from an anonymous Belgian retailer. You may also want to check the [business section](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html?format=&task=&att=&area=bus&numAtt=&numIns=&type=&sort=nameUp&view=table) of the UCI Machine Learning Repository.

Finding data on shoppers' purchases within the stores of a single mall may be more difficult, for a number of reasons:

1. It would require the cooperation of vendors, likely skeptical that sharing this information would be in their business interest.
2. It would require a way to link purchases by the same consumers across vendors, and identifying consumers this way would require sharing private information.

If you need longitudinal data describing the same individuals' purchases over time, you may want to search through published studies on consumer behavior. (Presumably some business researcher has approached this question before, and may even have recruited study participants to record their buying behavior over the length of a study.)